# Fatal error on ExpandedListView item click in Mono for Android

Tags: c#, android, mono, expandablelistview

I have an Android application built in Mono for Android in which I have a ExpandableListView.
I'm extending the BaseExpandableListAdapter class for my list adapter.

This is the OnCreate method of my activity:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{        
base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
lv = (ExpandableListView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.lv);
var expandableAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(this);
lv.SetAdapter(expandableAdapter);
}
```

The list is loaded properly, but when I click on an item I get a fatal exception.
I ran with debug and the exception occurs just after the execution of GetChildView method.

```
public override View GetChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, bool isLastChild,View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
if (convertView == null)
{
LayoutInflater infaInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
convertView = infaInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.childLayout, null);
}

TextView textView = (TextView)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.tvChild);
textView.SetText(GetChild(groupPosition, childPosition).ToString(), TextView.BufferType.Normal);
return textView;
}
```

This is the exception message:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(12474): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams 
:at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1806)
:at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1775)
:at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
```

Comment: Please show more of the exception message. So we can see where in the stack trace it's coming from your code. Also show the onClick event for the items.

Comment: I found a fix. It was the LinearLayout of the ExpandableListView. I removed the LinearLayout in the layout.axml file and the error is gone.